# trigonometry question asked in the STEP exam in 2021

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation

**Prove, from the identities for cos(A ± B), that cos a cos 3a ≡ 1/2 (\cos 4a +\cos 2a).**

**Find a similar identity for sin a cos 3a**

$$\cos(a+3a) =\cos(a)\cos(3a) -\sin(a)\sin(3a)$$

then maybe$$\cos(4a) + \sin(a)\sin(3a)  -> \cos(4a) + \sin(x)[\sin(a)\cos(2a)+\sin(2a)\cos(a)] $$

again on the sin(2a)$$\cos(4a) +\sin(x)[\sin(a)\cos(2a) + (\sin(a)\cos(a)+\sin(a)\cos(a))\cos(a)] $$

$$\cos(4a) + \sin(x)[\sin(a)\cos(2a) + \cos(a)(\sin(a)\cos(a)+\sin(a)\cos(a))]$$

$$\cos(4a) + \sin(x)[\sin(a)\cos(2a) + \cos(a)(2\sin(a)\cos(a))]$$

$$\cos(4a) + \sin^2(x)[\cos(2a) + 2\cos^2(a))]$$

$$\cos(4a) + [\cos^2-1][\cos(2a) + 2\cos^2(a))]$$

$$\cos(4a) + [\cos^2-1][\cos(2a) + 2\cos^2(a))]$$

---

*It's the first time I'm doing something like this and I think I am doing rubbish, could someone please give me hints on how to do it?*

Comment: Write out the identity for $\cos(a +3a)$ and  the one for $\cos(a-3a)$ then add them together.

Comment: @B.Goddard Found the solution thx! But how can you see it so quickly?

Comment: The $\cos(r)  - \cos(s)$ identity is based on the simultaneous consideration of the $\cos(a+b)$ and $\cos(a-b)$ identities.  The $\sin(r) - \sin(s)$ identity is based on the simultaneous consideration of the $\sin(a+b)$ and $\sin(a-b)$ identities.

Comment: Experience.  There are lots and lots of math tricks that rely on conjugate-y things like this.  It's the first thing most of us would try.  If you have $5-\sqrt{2}$  the solution probably uses $5+\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos(4a)=\cos(3a+a)=\cos(3a)\cos(a)-\sin(3a)\sin(a)$$

$$\cos(2a)=\cos(3a-a)=\cos(3a)\cos(a)+\sin(3a)\sin(a)$$

Take the sum:

$$\cos(4a)+\cos(a2)=2\cos(3a)\cos(a)$$

Divide $2$ on both sides:

$$\frac{\cos(4a)+\cos(a2)}{2}=\cos(3a)\cos(a)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(a+3a)+\cos(3a-a)=\cos(a)\cos(3a)-\sin(a)\sin(3a) + \cos(3a)\cos(a)+\sin(3a)\sin(a)$$
$$\cos(4a)+\cos(2a)=2\cos(a)\cos(3a)$$
$$1/2[\cos(4a)+\cos(2a)]=\cos(a)\cos(3a)$$

*As for the second part*

$$\sin(3a-a)+\sin(3a+a)=\sin(3a)\cos(a)-\sin(a)\cos(3a) + \sin(3a)\cos(a)-\sin(a)\cos(3a)$$
$$\sin(2a)+\sin(4a)= 2\sin(3a)\cos(a)$$
$$1/2[\sin(2a)+\sin(4a)]=\sin(3a)\cos(a)$$

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start with this:
$cos(X-Y)=cos X cos Y +sin X sin Y$ and $cos(X+Y)=cos X cos Y -sin X sin Y$. Thus $2\cos X \cos Y$ is $\cos(X-Y) +\cos(X+Y)$. You **wish** to prove $2\cos a\cos 3a=\cos 4a+\cos 2a$. So if we let $X=a$ and $Y=3a$ then $2\cos a \cos 3a=\cos 2a+\cos 4a$. Notice we have used the fact that $\cos -u$ and $\cos u$ are the same (that cos is even). Your attempt (with all due respect) of course, didn't choose the most direct route. Could you please try now to work on the next part [find a similar identity for $\sin a \cos 3a$]? If you are appearing for the STEP exam, I would recommend looking at more past papers for more similar problems.